# How do I understand answers which are too difficult to understand?

Tags: discussion, answers

I have found this site to be extremely useful but limited in a way. Often the questions which I ask have comparatively easier solutions but the answers which I receive involve high level concepts which I am not acquainted with. It seems that to be able to ask questions and receive answers which one is completely able to understand, he has to be an expert on the subject. However there is no platform to go from my current stage to that of an expert.

I think in order to surpass this difficulty, it should be made a rule that all the users should attempt to answer any question in the easiest way such that the maximum number of people can understand it and only do otherwise if explicitly mentioned. Any recommendations would be helpful. I hope this is seen in a positive way because many of my friends too complain about this.

Answer (score 13):

There shouldn't be a rule like this, as explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293086/162102).  We're a community of experts and people who want to learn more, not a "give me everything I need" service.  In some cases it would make sense for you to ask followup questions (after making an attempt to learn on your own).

That said, not everybody who comes with a question is an expert.  Some are experienced practitioners; some are high-school students encountering the topic for the first time; some are hobbyists figuring things out on their own.  Don't make demands of answerers (who after all are providing a public service), but it's completely ok to briefly describe your context.  Conscientious answerers will try to calibrate their responses to your level of knowledge.  It's ok to tell us what you do (and don't) know already, if your explanation of what you've already tried doesn't make it clear enough by itself.

You can find examples of this approach on Mi Yodeya, the site about Judaism.  Jewish law is complex and has a jargon all its own; further, most of our important sources are written in Hebrew (or sometimes Aramaic), languages that not everybody is fluent in.  We try to make sure our answers are accessible anyway (for example, pushing for translations or at least summaries when non-English sources are quoted), but I've noticed that if an asker says "I don't understand Hebrew" or "I'm only a beginner in this area", answerers tend to take extra care.  (This care might come in the form of links to background material.)  Further, we sometimes get questions from people who tell us they're not Jewish (the site is for everybody, after all), and I see answerers take extra care to explain or link to explanations of not only the things I've mentioned but anything that depends on the shared context of Jewish practice.  Answerers don't have to do these things, but most recognize that doing so leads to better answers.

Comment: Great answer, upvoted. FWIW I didn't mean to come across as some jerk that doesn't care what the reader understands. In fact many of my own answers *extensively* explain what's going on under the hood, as opposed to just spoon-feeding the OP with a "try this" copy-pasta answer. [Here's one of many examples on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43056388/1188513). What I meant is that if my answers touch on concepts that are foreign to the OP (e.g. *extensible COM interfaces*), then it's the OP's job to research about these things.

Comment: @Meta'sMug I didn't take you as some jerk who doesn't care.  I wanted to expand on your answer, not contradict it.

Answer (score 12):

> *[...], but the answers which I receive involve high level concepts which I am not acquainted with.*

Isn't that awesome? You get to get acquainted with *new concepts* and broaden your horizons!

...as long as you're willing to *put in the effort* to learn.

Nobody said it was going to be easy.

> *it should be made a rule that all the users should attempt to answer any question in the easiest way such that the maximum number of people can understand it*

How about *it should be made a rule that all users asking a question should be willing to put in the effort to learn*? This means research. It can mean work, and sometimes sweat.

Stack Exchange questions (and their answers) aren't meant to be useful and interesting *only for the person asking it*. Other people will read, and learn things too. If you have a question that involves concepts you're not aware of, and get an answer that explains these things, or hints at them, your job is to inquire about these new concepts (quite likely that your research takes you to another Stack Exchange Q&A). What's "easy to understand" for one person could very well be way too vague for another.

Dumbing everything down serves no one. And how do you dumb down an answer that explains how overload resolution works in C# when you're in a generic type that overrides a virtual method from its base class and overloads that method in the derived type? If you read the answer and some concepts are unfamiliar to *you*, then *you* have some research to do - and 99.9% of the time the information is right there at the tip of your fingers. In the documentation, or in another Q&A.

If you want an answer about flowers and bees for a question asking how babies are made, you can always try putting "please tell me like I'm 5" in the question, and most answerers will take it into account in their answers, to varying degrees (they're *answers*, not *tutorials*). But don't blame the answerer for treating you like a grown-up.